# Unable to automatically install python packages from script

Tags: python, pip, installation-package

I am in need of installing Python packages directly from a script. I know this is generally viewed as bad practice, but the script needs to be entirely self-contained. I tried this option which I found quite handy:

```
import subprocess
import sys    
list_of_packages=['package_1', 'package_2', ... 'package_n']    
def install(package):
    subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, "-m", "pip", "install", package]
for package in list_of_packages:
    install(package)
```

This works on a machine with `Python 3.8.3` installed. However, when I try to execute the script on another machine with `Python 3.10.0` installed, I get the following error:

```
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['[PYTHONPATH]\\pythonw.exe', '-m', 'pip', 'install', 'package_1']' returned non-zero exit status 2.
```

I don't understand whether this is due to the different Python versions (perhaps the `subprocess` and `sys` modules have been modified) or whether there is some other module in my old machine which makes it work (`Python 3.10.0` has been just recently installed in the new machine and no external packages have been installed yet).

EDIT: After @Passi 's answer I tried reinstalling Python and checking the required box to add pip to the `PATH` variable. Unfortunately this did not work. I am able to manually install packages on command prompt typing:

```
python -m pip install 'package_name'
```

but when I run the script, either from IDLE or command prompt I always get the same error. Changing pip to pip3 did not solve this either.

Comment: Do you have pip installed for Python 3.10? To check run `python3.10 -m pip -v`

Comment: @MatteoZanoni Yes, pip is regularly installed

Answer (score 0):

You can try pip3.
It is important that pip or pip3 is as a `PATH` variable.
There is a "bug" that after installing Python version 3.10 that the `Python3 PATH` variable is removed.

[image: epython installer img]

Check the box and your pip will be in the `PATH`variable

It would be better when you do something like that with a PoweShell oder Bash  script.

Comment: Check out the edit in the main question. Unfortunately, this did not work

Comment: is pip3 install package working

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the issue by downgrading to Python 3.8. It seems like there are clashes between some of the packages and Python 3.10.